# Rename nested object keys with q + counter variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that has a nested object within it. When I try to insert this data into a database table, I get an error because it's looking for a column called `ga_questions`.

What I need is to break down `ga_questions` to be a key/value like `"q1": "false"` so I can insert each checkbox value into the DB. The key needs to increment for each checkbox so the next entry would like `"q2": "true"`, and so on and so forth.

I'm having trouble getting the incrementing to work.

```js
q_obj = {
  "GAInsSig": "Skylar",
  "GAnotes": "",
  "GAInsSig2": "",
  "ga_questions": [{
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": false
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": true
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": true
  }, {
    "ga_checkbox": true
  }],
  "badge_num": "12345",
  "work_order": "123",
  "unit_num": "123",
  "job_num": "GET",
  "date_completed": "2024-01-17"
}
```

Below is the code I have tried so far.

```
let i = 1;
q_obj.map((el) => {
  let question = "q";
  question.concat(i);
  el.question = el.ga_checkbox;
  i++;
  delete el.ga_checkbox;
});
```

This will rename my keys to just question. Is there another way to do this so that I can have the keys of this nested object start with `'q'` + the value of `i`?

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired value of `ga_questions`? Right now it's an array of objects.

Comment: Should `ga_questions` be removed or should the nesting still be there?

Comment: Lots of sketchy things here.  Are you aware that `.map` allows you to get the index  `q_obj.map((el, i) => {`?  There is no need to keep track of `i` externally.  Also, `.map` _returns_ the array it generates so you can just return the element values rather than assigning them to an array of your own.  To have `map` only produce side effects is an anti-pattern [listed in the documentation of `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#side-effectful_mapping).  Furthermore, `question.concat(i)` doesn't modify the value of `question`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the nesting with `Object.assign`, then remove the `ga_questions` property.

```js
const q_obj = {"GAInsSig":"Skylar","GAnotes":"","GAInsSig2":"",
"ga_questions":[{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":false},{"ga_checkbox":true},{"ga_checkbox":true},{"ga_checkbox":true}],
"badge_num":"12345","work_order":"123","unit_num":"123","job_num":"GET","date_completed":"2024-01-17"};
Object.assign(q_obj, ...q_obj.ga_questions.map((o, i) => ({['q' + (i + 1)]: o.ga_checkbox})));
delete q_obj.ga_questions;
console.log(q_obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of UYM array mapping and dynamic object keys, for example:

```
let q_obj = {
      "GAInsSig":"Skylar",
      "GAnotes":"",
      "GAInsSig2":"",
      "ga_questions":[
        {"ga_checkbox":false},
        {"ga_checkbox":false},
        {"ga_checkbox":true},
        {"ga_checkbox":true},
        {"ga_checkbox":true}
      ],
      "badge_num":"12345",
      "work_order":"123",
      "unit_num":"123",
      "job_num":"GET",
      "date_completed":"2024-01-17"
    };
    let i = 1;
    q_obj.ga_questions = q_obj.ga_questions.map(el => {
      let questionKey = "q" + i;
      let questionValue = el.ga_checkbox;
      i++;
      return { [questionKey]: questionValue };
    });
```

Comment: No need to worry about your English, just make sure your answers are straight to the point. Even if there are grammatical errors the site editors will fix it up for you! If you want to be a little more confident with your writing feel free to install something like Grammarly, it will help you avoid most basic grammar mistakes.